# Change path symbols \ to /

Tags: c++, string, windows

I have a string path to my file that I want to execute. It is for example:

```
E:\folderA\folderB\myfile.exe
```

If I write this path and I try to execute file there it says that file doesn't exist.

When I write it like that. Then it works.

```
  E:/folderA/folderB/myFile.exe
```

How do I change \ to /  ?

Comment: You need to use `escaped backslashes` in C(++), `E:\\folderA\\folderB\\myfile.exe`

Comment: Okay, then how do I change \ to \\ in string?

Comment: Where are the strings coming from in the first place?

Comment: `GetTempPathA(MAX_PATH, tempPath); 
 string fullPath = (string)tempPath + "/" + data.fileName;`

Comment: You might want to take a look at [Boost.Filesystem](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/filesystem/doc/index.htm)...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may just use this:

```
std::string str=R"(E:\folderA\folderB\myfile.exe)";
```

and everything will be fine

[Live Demo](http://cpp.sh/3yw6)

Answer (score 2):

Windows is quirky about whether Unix (/) or windows (\) separators are accepted.

You also need to escape '\' in a string

```
const char * bad = "C:\hello\world.txt"
const char *good = "C:\\hello\\world.txt"
```

std::string::replace allows substitution.

Comment: A `char*` to a constant c string.  That is bad form.  You should use a `std::string`

Comment: Okay, how replace function should look, because `replace(fullPath.begin(), fullPath.end(), '\', '\\');` doesn't work.

Comment: @DeKirvis You didn't get what an escaped character means, did you?

Comment: @DeKirvis `'\'` doesn't form a valid character literal.

Answer (score 0):

```
GetTempPathA(MAX_PATH, tempPath);
string fullPath = (string)tempPath + "/" + data.fileName;

std::replace(fullPath.begin(), fullPath.end(), '\\', '/');
```